# Using flutter Dio, I want to post/patch a json object map(below) of field and list of imagefiles and string field to api

Tags: flutter, dio

Here is the JSON object below that I want to post using flutter Dio. I am facing a problem in posting the img_list since it is the combination of image file and string field, whereas in dio or any other package I found there is request.file or request.field I couldn't find the combination of both and solve posting the list of image objects.

```
{
   "offer_price": 20.0,
   "offer_price": 20.0,
   "is_offer": false,
   "img_list": [
     {
        "alt": "ss_bg1.png",
        "photo": "http://.../.../ss_bg.png"
     },
     {
        "alt": "ss_bg2.png",
        "photo": "http://.../.../ss_bg2.png"
     }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code may it works

```
_dio.options.headers.addAll({'Content-Type': 'application/json-patch+json'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Dio package you can:

If you want to post single nested Map lets say:

**Wrong:**

```
FormData.fromMap({

 parent_key: { child_key: child_value }

})
```

You need to convert it to:

**Correct**

```
FormData.fromMap({

 parent_key.child_key: child_value

})
```

And if you wanted to post list of maps lets say:

**Wrong:**

```
FormData.fromMap({

 parent_key: [

   { child_key: child_value },
   { child_key: child_value_02 }
]

})
```

You need to convert it to:

**Correct**

```
FormData.fromMap({

 parent_key[0]child_key: child_value
 parent_key[1]child_key: child_value_02

})
```